# Cannot Connect to HornetQ Connection Factory in JBoss 5 with Spring 3

Tags: spring, jboss, jms, hornetq

Locally, my application connects fine to the built in netty ConnectionFactory and I have no problems on start up or sending topic messages. My local box is stand-alone JBoss 5.1 and stand-alone HornetQ.

However, when deploying to our DEV server (running clustered JBoss 5.1 and clustered HornetQ) I'm not able to connect, getting the following stack trace:

```
ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost].[/eShowroom]] (main) Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of cla>\ss org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'topicConnectionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: ConnectionFactory not bound
```

I'm trying to use the default, built-in netty connector with no extra configuration except for my own JMS Topic. I'm relatively unaware of the DEV server setup as it is out of my control and *fairly* black box to me.

**applicationContext.xml** (in `$JBOSS_HOME/server/default/deploy/application.war/WEB-INF`):

```
    <bean id="jndiTemplate" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate">
       <property name="environment">
            <props>
                <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory</prop>
                <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">jnp://${jboss.bind.address:localhost}:1099</prop>
                <prop key="java.naming.factory.url.pkgs">org.jboss.naming</prop>
            </props>
       </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="topicConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiTemplate" ref="jndiTemplate"></property>
        <property name="jndiName" value="/ConnectionFactory"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="cacheTopic" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiTemplate" ref="jndiTemplate"></property>
        <property name="jndiName" value="/topic/myCacheTopic"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jmsDestinationResolver" class="org.springframework.jms.support.destination.JndiDestinationResolver">
        <property name="jndiTemplate" ref="jndiTemplate"/>
        <property name="cache" value="true"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="messageSendTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="topicConnectionFactory"/>
        <property name="destinationResolver" ref="jmsDestinationResolver"/>
        <property name="pubSubDomain" value="true"/>
    </bean>
```

**hornetq-jms.xml** (in `$JBOSS_HOME/server/default/deploy/hornetq.sar`)

```
    <connection-factory name="NettyConnectionFactory">
      <xa>true</xa>
      <connectors>
         <connector-ref connector-name="netty"/>
      </connectors>
      <entries>
         <entry name="/ConnectionFactory"/>
         <entry name="/XAConnectionFactory"/>
      </entries>
   </connection-factory>

   <connection-factory name="NettyThroughputConnectionFactory">
      <xa>true</xa>
       <connectors>
         <connector-ref connector-name="netty-throughput"/>
       </connectors>
        <entries>
            <entry name="/ThroughputConnectionFactory"/>
            <entry name="/XAThroughputConnectionFactory"/>
        </entries>
    </connection-factory>

   <connection-factory name="InVMConnectionFactory">
      <xa>true</xa>
      <connectors>
         <connector-ref connector-name="in-vm"/>
      </connectors>
      <entries>
         <entry name="java:/ConnectionFactory"/>
         <entry name="java:/XAConnectionFactory"/>
      </entries>
   </connection-factory>
```

The only difference between local and DEV that I can easily spot is in hornetq-configuration.xml.

DEV **hornetq-configuration.xml** (same path as hornetq-jms.xml)

```
   <broadcast-groups>
      <broadcast-group name="bg-group1">
         <group-address>${hornetq.broadcast.bg-group1.address:231.7.7.7}</group-address>
         <group-port>${hornetq.broadcast.bg-group1.port:9876}</group-port>
         <broadcast-period>5000</broadcast-period>
         <connector-ref>netty</connector-ref>
      </broadcast-group>
   </broadcast-groups>

   <discovery-groups>
      <discovery-group name="dg-group1">
         <group-address>${hornetq.discovery.dg-group1.address:231.7.7.7}</group-address>
         <group-port>${hornetq.discovery.dg-group1.port:9876}</group-port>
         <refresh-timeout>10000</refresh-timeout>
      </discovery-group>
   </discovery-groups>

   <cluster-connections>
      <cluster-connection name="my-cluster">
         <address>jms</address>  
         <connector-ref>netty</connector-ref>
          <discovery-group-ref discovery-group-name="dg-group1"/>
      </cluster-connection>
   </cluster-connections>
```

Comment: Have you tried         
<property name="jndiName" value="ConnectionFactory"></property>

That is, without the leading "/" in the name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it turns out that for whatever reason this was a timing issue in a clustered environment. The bean(s) that needed the connection factory were simply forced to wait until everything else was up and running before spinning up.